# DISCORD.JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to forward all messages that come into Channel X to Channel Y, that works fine.
But I also want to forward every picture to channel Y when there is a picture.

Getting this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Thats my code I hope someone can help me

```
bot.on('message',async msg => {
    if(msg.channel.id != readingchannel)return
    let content = msg.content
    let pic =  msg.attachments
    let alertembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("TEST")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setDescription(msg.content)
    bot.channels.cache.get(writingchannel).send(alertembed)
    if(msg.attachments.length >= 1)return
    let alertembed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("TEST")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setDescription(msg.content)
    .setImage(msg.attachments[0].url)
    bot.channels.cache.get(writingchannel).send(alertembed2)
});
```

Comment: The error means that `msg.attachments[0]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you're checking for the attachment, you return if the attachment is found, which I'm assuming isn't the intended behavior. If you get a message with an attachment, it will return, but if there's no attachment, the embed will send with the (non-existent) image. See the problem?

To fix this all you'd have to do is change
`if(msg.attachments.length >= 1)return` to something like
`if (msg.attachments.length < 1) return;`

Now, when you send a message without any attachment, it will simply return without trying to access the `url` property of the non-existent attachment.